# DataTables js didn't sort strings correct

Tags: javascript, sorting, datatables

I use the latest DataTables.js with jquery 3.3.1.

This is the table data structure

```
<table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 100 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 11 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Should sort row 1

```
to row 1, row 11, row 100
or row 100, row 11, row 1
```

but it do

```
row 1, row 100, row 11
```

or

```
row 11, row 100, row 1
```

This is the normal sort behavior in javascript,
what also not sorting correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sure, your rows are sorted ***lexically*** (in alphabetical order). if you would append your jQuery code, I may suggest what to change to get it fixed.

Comment: What's your javascript code ?

Comment: It looks like you want to sort based on the numeric values embedded in some text. This looks very similar to this question: [Datatables sorting - how to ignore text in column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60918299/datatables-sorting-how-to-ignore-text-in-column). Does that help?

Comment: I use the default settings like  in the examples of Datatables js. So it is only the jquery load function call.
Please look to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking how DataTables js is sorting par Example

```
row 1, row 100, row 11
```

Now, i hope, i found a good solution and also develop some DataTable with native JavaScript.

Here fond the source-code:
https://github.com/chrobaks/netcodev-datatable

Here you can find a demo:
https://www.netcodev.de/datatable/

Answer (score 1):

Set type="textNum" in column definition
and then implement custom sort using `jquery.extend jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort,{//comparator function})`

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "textNum-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return a.match(/\s*\d*\s/)[0]- b.match(/\s*\d*\s/)[0]
    },
    "textNum-desc": function ( a, b ) {
       return b.match(/\s*\d*\s/)[0]- a.match(/\s*\d*\s/)[0]
    }
});
```

Run the following snippet

```js
$("#table_id").dataTable({
"columnDefs": [
    { type: 'textNum',"targets": 0 },
    { type: 'textNum',"targets": 1 },
  ]
})
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "textNum-asc": function ( a, b ) {
       //regex will match first number i.e number to right of row
        return a.match(/\s*\d*\s/)[0]- b.match(/\s*\d*\s/)[0] 
    },
    "textNum-desc": function ( a, b ) {
       return b.match(/\s*\d*\s/)[0]- a.match(/\s*\d*\s/)[0]
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" >
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 6 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 4 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Row 3 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 7 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 10 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 0 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 11 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 3 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Supercool, but i work with Vanilla JS.. you only need less than 15 lines of code to sort correct with holding index.

Comment: You said in the question name " sorting in datatable jquery" thats why i replied with this answer

Comment: In the vanilla js you can use c.sort(function(a,b) { return a.split("\s")[1]-b.split("\s")[1] } just one line