# Is there a way to get DataTables to sort when a title attribute has a break in it?

Tags: html, datatables

I would like to have line breaks (I am using `&#10;`) in the title attribute of my `Decimal` column in order to show a breakdown of how something is calculated, but DataTables is not able to sort  that column when I do this.  This example sorts fine if i simply remove the `&#10;` and use a `,` instead, but I was hoping to display them with the break.

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<table id="foo">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Fraction</th>
  <th>Decimal</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>     
      <td>10/9</td>
      <td>
        <div title="A: 9.6&#10;B: 15.0&#10;C: 20.0" class="hoverable">44.6</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>     
      <td>0/9</td>
      <td>
         <div title="A: 9.0&#10;B: 15.8&#10;C: 5.0" class="hoverable">29.8</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>     
      <td>1/9</td>
      <td>
        <div title="A: 9.0&#10;B: 12.4&#10;C: 20.0" class="hoverable">41.4</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>     
      <td>7/9</td>
      <td>
        <div title="A: 60.0&#10;B: 19.7&#10;C: 20.0" class="hoverable">99.7</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#foo').DataTable();
} );
```

CSS

```
.hoverable {
    color: rgb(0, 14, 229);
}

.hoverable:hover {
    cursor: help;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rhn1szkx/2/

Comment: One approach: You can use the DataTables `orderData` feature - see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60918299/datatables-sorting-how-to-ignore-text-in-column/60918789#60918789). Currently, the entire contents of each "Decimal" cell is treated as a string of text: `<div title="A: 9.6&#10;B: 1...`.

Comment: There are also options using [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data). That has mechanisms for displaying a value one way, and sorting it in a different way.