# Datatables cannot sort correctly when using parenthesis, '%' sign and comma. Simple JsFiddle

Tags: datatables

I want to sort a column full of cells with different symbols in it, including '%', comma, and '()'.I tried implementing datatables plugin formatted numbers. It didn't work. I also tried using a plugin negative parenthesis, which I was not able to fully put into code. I would really appreciate if you check out my jsfiddle.I want to make my code pretend like there is no symbol and sort based on sole presence of numbers. Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5gqpn8c9/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    $('#example').DataTable({
      "bPaginate": true,
      "bLengthChange": false,
      "bFilter": true,
      "bInfo": false,
      //"scrollY": "425px",
      "scrollCollapse": false,
      "order": [
        [2, "desc"]
      ],
      "bAutoWidth": false
    });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js">
</script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js">
</script>

<head id="head">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Covid-19 Dashboard</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
  <table id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>102(1%)</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>103(2%)</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>104(1.00%)</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>5,545(3.83%)</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td> 552(4.51%)</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>10,7(2%)</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  
  </body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to ignore text when sorting numbers in DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60918299/datatables-sorting-how-to-ignore-text-in-column/60918789#60918789)?

Comment: Another approach: Look at DataTables' support for [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data), as an alternative.

Comment: Bro, I am really not that familiar with dataTables. All I want to do is get this result while sorting descending: 5,545(3.83%), 552(4.51%),104(1.00%).

Comment: is there any way if you could just edit my fiddle and make it sort that way somehow. I am pretty exhausted and this bug keeps me slowing down.