# Secondary Ordering for Column in Datatables

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

As you can see from the screenshot below, I have a datatables displaying two related but disparate bits of data, Avg Score and # of Ratings:

[image: screenshot]

When ordering by this column, it would be preferred if I could order by Avg Score first (numeric) and then # of Ratings second (numeric) but also keep them displayed in a single column.

I was thinking about how to modify the value of the data-order attribute to do manipulate a thing but I couldn't think of any solutions.

Anyone else solved this issue.

The data cell looks like this:

```
<td class="text-center sorting_1" data-search="-1" data-order="5.00">

  <div class="mb-2">            

  <span class="badge badge-success">            
    5.00
  </span>

  </div>

  <small class="text-muted">
    10 ratings
  </small>
             
</td>
```

Comment: One approach: You can use the [`orderData`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderData) option for this. For example, add two [hidden](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.visible) columns to your table - one containing the average score number and one containing the rating number. Then use `orderData` to delegate the search order from your visible column to these hidden columns. You can see a basic example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60918789/12567365). - except in your case, you have 2 target columns, rather than 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom sorting function for the column of your interest.

The snippet:

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
    "aoColumns": [{
        "bSortable": true}, {"bSortable": true}, {"sType": "customAvgScoreSort", "bSortable": true}]
});

// custom sorting.......
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort["customAvgScoreSort-desc"] = function (x, y) {
    return parseFloat($(y).find('span').text()) - parseFloat($(x).find('span').text()) || parseInt($(y).siblings('small').text()) - parseInt($(x).siblings('small').text());
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort["customAvgScoreSort-asc"] = function (x, y) {
    return parseFloat($(x).find('span').text()) - parseFloat($(y).find('span').text()) || parseInt($(x).siblings('small').text()) - parseInt($(y).siblings('small').text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Unique deals</th>
        <th>AVG score</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Sales development</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>
            <div class="mb-2">
                <span class="badge badge-success">
                    5.0
                </span>
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">
                2 ratings
            </small>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sales development</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>
            <div class="mb-2">
                <span class="badge badge-success">
                    5.0
                </span>
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">
                1 ratings
            </small>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sales development</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>
            <div class="mb-2">
                <span class="badge badge-success">
                    5.0
                </span>
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">
                10 ratings
            </small>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sales development</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>
            <div class="mb-2">
                <span class="badge badge-success">
                    5.0
                </span>
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">
                3 ratings
            </small>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```